# Tampermonkey script to remove a division and make other divisions auto-align

Tags: javascript, html, css, tampermonkey

I'm new to JS & HTML, and I'm trying to tamper a website with tamper monkey.

It won't work without an account so I can't give you the link to it, but it is just like Twitter.

I managed to remove certain divisions (just like certain tweets in Twitter), giving a list of IDs, with the following script:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         test
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/test
// @version      0.1
// @description  test
// @author       test
// @match        https://test.com/*
// @grant        GM_log
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
// @require      https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// ==/UserScript==

/* globals jQuery, $, waitForKeyElements */

(function() {
    'use strict';

    const black_list = ['id1', 'id2'];
    waitForKeyElements(".vue-recycle-scroller__item-view", function() {
        remove_test(black_list);
    });
})();

function remove_test(black_list) {
    const feeds = document.querySelectorAll('.vue-recycle-scroller__item-view').forEach(e => {
        const htmlString = e.outerHTML;
        if (isIdInHTML(htmlString, black_list, true)) {
            e.remove();
        }
    });
}

function isIdInHTML(targetString, idsArray, verbose = false) {
    for (const id of idsArray) {
        const substring = `<span title="${id}">${id}</span>`;;
        if (targetString.includes(substring)) {
            if (verbose) {
                GM_log(`Removing: ${id}`);
            }
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

It works, but the removed divisions will leave blanks in the column.

I tried to maunally remove divisions in Twitter, and I noticed that Twitter's tweets HTML looks like this:

```
<div style="position: relative; min-height: 10169px;">
<div data-testid="cellInnerDiv" style="transform: translateY(0px); position: absolute; width: 100%;">...</div>
<div data-testid="cellInnerDiv" style="transform: translateY(119px); position: absolute; width: 100%;">...</div>
<div data-testid="cellInnerDiv" style="transform: translateY(520px); position: absolute; width: 100%;">...</div>
...
</div>
```

... and after I tried to delete a certain `<div data-testid="cellInnerDiv"...`, all tweets' `translateY` will change automatically, and so that they can automatically go top to fill the blanks left by the deleted division.

And the website I'm working on doesn't have this feature -- `translateY`s will remain the same after I delete some divisions manually. I suspect this is the reason why there will be blanks after my script deletes some divisions.

The website I'm working on looks like:

```
<div class="vue-recycle-scroller__item-wrapper" style="min-height: 8234px;">
<div class="vue-recycle-scroller__item-view" style="transform: translateY(0px);">...</div>
<div class="vue-recycle-scroller__item-view" style="transform: translateY(506px);">...</div>
<div class="vue-recycle-scroller__item-view" style="transform: translateY(1010px);">...</div>
...
</div>
```

Is there any way to remove certain divisions with tampermonkey script, and make other divions auto-align to the top, like twitter does?